# Observable not working properly angular2?

Tags: angular

```
sendMsg(msgToSend: string, reciepient: string){
    console.log(msgToSend, reciepient, this.user);
    let newObj = {from: this.user['name'], msg: msgToSend};
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
        let name = reciepient;
        this.service.getUser(name).then(user => this.reciepient = user);
    })
    if(this.reciepient){
        console.log(this.reciepient['inbox']);
        this.reciepient['inbox'].unshift(newObj);
    } else {
        console.log('Try again!!');
    }

}
```

I am calling above method through my template

```
<input #reciepient placeholder="Reciepient"/>
<input #message placeholder="Enter your message"/>
<button (click)="sendMsg(message.value, reciepient.value)">Send message</button>
```

I have user data with two users, `Ram` and `Sai`. I logged as Ram and Sending message to Sai. In recipient box I mentioned Sai and typed some message in message box. When I click on send message, first time the message not getting pushed into sai's inbox as doing in sendMsg() method because it is going to else statement and printing `Try again!!`. On second+ clicks its getting pushed. In the same way, once push success, now If I mentioned no name in recipient box, for first time click it is taking the previous value that is Sai and pushing message, and second+ clicks it is taking null value and prints console message `Try again!!`. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Since `Observables` are doing asynchronuous work, you have to put any followup code that needs data from the subscription into the callback:

```ts
sendMsg(msgToSend: string, reciepient: string){
    console.log(msgToSend, reciepient, this.user);

    let newObj = {from: this.user['name'], msg: msgToSend};

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
        let name = reciepient;

        this.service.getUser(name).then(user => {
            this.reciepient = user;

            if(this.reciepient){
                console.log(this.reciepient['inbox']);
                this.reciepient['inbox'].unshift(newObj);
            } else {
                console.log('Try again!!');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: still getting same output

Comment: Could you try and debug it? You can set breakpoints when debugging with your webbrowser and step through every instruction. Just press `F12` to bring up the developer tools, switch to the `Sources` tab and chose the js file.